# node.js on mac in 32 bit mode?

Tags: node.js, macos, appjs

For the app.js I need to have my node.js in 32 bit mode.

```
node me$ file `which node`
/usr/local/bin/node: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/node (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/local/bin/node (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
node me$
```

Does this mean, that it is installes in two executable versions(32 and 64 bit) on my system? If so, how can I tell the executable to run the 32 bit version?

Answer (score 0):

On this page: https://nodejs.org/download/ you can download and install the 32-bit version, and node should then run only the 32-bit version.  Be sure to remove any other instances you have of it first.  You can verify which you have with a command like this:

```
$ file `which node`
```

I have the 64-bit version and I get:

```
$ file `which node`
/usr/local/bin/node: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

You should get something about 32-bit once you get the 32-bit version installed.

Comment: I found out that I can run the 32- bit version with the arch command: arch -i386 node --harmony. But I still get this error: AppJS requires Node is run with the --harmony command line flag;

Comment: What version of node are you running?  I think you need version 0.11 or higher but I'm not positive.